# SP 2013 error - The password supplied with the username was not correct

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I problem with account in SharePoint and I have tried everything. Password is correct but I cannot get it working in SP 2013.
Also solutions from [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/79551/the-password-supplied-with-the-username-xxx-was-not-correct-verify-that-it-was/195419?noredirect=1#comment206951_195419) and MSDN. Distributed cache if offline and it does not start.

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2014 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Windows\system32> Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -EA silentlycontinue
PS C:\Windows\system32>
PS C:\Windows\system32> $m = Get-SPManagedAccount -Identity domain\svc-acc
PS C:\Windows\system32>
PS C:\Windows\system32> Set-SPManagedAccount -Identity $m  -ExistingPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString "111111" -AsPlain
Text -force) -confirm

Confirm
Are you sure you want to perform this action?
Performing the operation "Set-SPManagedAccount" on target "domain\svc-acc".
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"): y
Set-SPManagedAccount : The password supplied with the username domain\svc-acc was not correct. Verify that it
was entered correctly and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-SPManagedAccount -Identity $m  -ExistingPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString "S1 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...tManagedAccount:SPCmdletSetManagedAccount) [Set-SPManage
   dAccount], Win32Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletSetManagedAccount
```

Whatever I do I get password problem? Any suggestions? Thanks
Strange thing is that this was working and suddenly it stop working, not changes where done to this account.

Also when I try to run service I am getting this error:

```
Application Server Administration job failed for service instance Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceInstance (fe8e6c98-02fd-4be2-800d-45f0d158fe68).

Reason: The password of the search service account has expired. To update the password visit the services on server page and update the password for the search service.

Technical Support Details:
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8007042D): The password of the search service account has expired. To update the password visit the services on server page and update the password for the search service.
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceInstance.Synchronize()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do the following :

- Go to Services and sort by “Log On As” to get the list of services configured to run under that account. (`domain\svc-acc`)
- Right Click on the service > Properties > Log On Tab > Try to provide the user credentials again and stop and start your search service .
- Restart SharePoint Timer Service.
- Perform `iisreset /noforce`

If the issue still , try to  Repairs the local managed account credential deployment by running [Repair-SPManagedAccountDeployment](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607627.aspx)

For more details check

- [Service Accounts Passwords Change Guide](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/charliechirapuntu/2013/01/16/sharepoint-2010-service-accounts-passwords-change-guide/)
- [Updating passwords on SharePoint](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/seanearp/2011/01/25/updating-passwords-on-sharepoint-2010/)

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things to check.

- Go to Central admin > Security > Configure Managed Account...On this page Click on your service account and next page Make sure it is not schedule automatic update.
- Also make sure the Password in the AD is not expired.

You can try to change the password from Central admin on the configured Managed Account...Please click on use existing password and supply it. If it is successful but still Search is throwing the error then run the following command.`Repair-SPManagedAccountDeployment`.

I reset IIS after the password Update to make sure all the related app gets the new password.

In some case, we ends up to clear the config cache on SharePoint server after password change.